# Please help me understand the warning generated in RefTest(). [-Wincompati

Tags: c, pointers

warning: returning 'struct example_str **' from a function with incompatible return type 'struct example_str *' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
return &(example1_str->member2[index]);

Please help understand why the warning is being generated. When example1_struct->member[index] is called, my understanding is it should return (struct example_struct*) Please help me understand the reason for warning. Thank you in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "stdbool.h"

struct example_str{
    int member1;
    struct example_str* member2[5];
};
struct example_str* Reftest(int index);
void function2(int id, int* SigVal);

struct example_str* example1_str;

int main()
{
    _Bool test;
    int Val = (int) test;
    function2(10,&Val);
    return 0;
}

void function2(int id, int* SigVal){

    struct example_str* ptr_to_str;
    ptr_to_str = Reftest(1);
    ptr_to_str -> member2[1] -> member1 = id;
    printf("%d",ptr_to_str -> member2[1] -> member1);
}

struct example_str* Reftest(int index){
    return &(example1_str->member2[index]);
}
```

Comment: It looks like you should do `return example1_str->member2[index];` instead of `return &(example1_str->member2[index]);`. (Remove the extra `&`). Also make sure the pointers to dereference are initialized properly before dereferencing.

Comment: @Kung Pao What is unclear in the warning message?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I am new to C and I am trying to understand the warning about pointer mismatch types. Here member2[index] is of type (struct example_str*) then why does it complain and expect a return type of (struct example_str**). Hopefully that helps.

Comment: In your comment (that should be added to the question) you correctly state the type of `example1_str->member2[index]`, but you return `&(example1_str->member2[index])`. This is the address of a variable that can hold this type.

Comment: @Bodo When you do (example_str->member2[index]), shouldn't that return a value rather than an address? My understanding was if I do an &(example_str->member2[index]) will return address of type (struct example_str*). May be I am understanding wrong. Please help.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the more specific question or clarification from your comments there. `struct example_str* member2[5];` is an array of 5 pointers, so the value is a pointer. If you add an `&` it is the address of a variable which has a value of type *pointer to your structure*, so it results in a pointer to a pointer to a structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
struct example_str
{
    int                 member1;
    struct example_str* member2[5];
};
```

`example_str` has 2 members and

- `member1` is `int`
- `member2` is `struct example_str*[5]`, a.k.a. an array of 5 pointers to `struct example_str`, from `member2[0]` to `member2[4]`. 5 pointers.

`refTest` returns `struct example_str*`, the same type of each `member2`

You can align the declarations to see better

```
struct example_str
{
    int                 member1;
    struct example_str* member2[5];
};

    struct example_str* Reftest(int index);
```

So it is clear that whathever `member2` is, it is the same that `Reftest()` returns.

So if you declare, as you did

```
struct example_str* Reftest(int index)
{
    return &(example1_str->member2[index]);
}
```

As `&` is the operator `address of`, you are returning the address of `member2[]`, that is itself a pointer --- `struct example_str*` --- and for sure its type is `struct example_str**`

The compilers says that

```
so0729.c:35:12: warning: returning 'struct example_str **' from a function
 with incompatible return type  
struct example_str *' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   35 |     return &(example1_str->member2[index]);
      |            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

And it is what it is. Just take the `&` off.

Consider using `typedef`. It is usual and can lead to a code easier to read. And avoid global things declared outside `main()`

#### Example

This is a variation of your code using the pointers to pass references back and forth to the structs

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct st_example_str
{
    int                    member1;
    struct st_example_str* member2[5];

} Example;

Example* Reftest(Example*, unsigned);

void function2(Example*, unsigned, int* SigVal);

int main()
{
    Example A = {.member1 = 10};
    Example B = {.member1 = 11};
    Example C = {.member1 = 12};
    Example D = {.member1 = 13};
    Example E = {.member1 = 14};

    Example ex1;
    ex1.member1    = 1;
    ex1.member2[0] = &A;
    ex1.member2[1] = &B;
    ex1.member2[2] = &C;
    ex1.member2[3] = &D;
    ex1.member2[4] = &E;  // not used

    C.member2[0] = &ex1;  // cycle
    D.member2[0] = &ex1;  // cycle
    E.member2[0] = &ex1;  // cycle

    char test = 42;
    int  Val  = (int)test;

    function2(&ex1, 2, &Val);  // should set member1 of C to 42...

    printf("ids (member1) pointed from the array inside ex1: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i += 1)
        printf("%d ", ex1.member2[i]->member1);
    printf("\n");

    printf("member1 for ex1: %d\n", ex1.member1);
    return 0;
}

void function2(Example* E, unsigned id, int* SigVal)
{
    // sets member1 of struct pointed by E->member[id] to
    // the value pointed to by SigVal
    Example* ptr_to_str             = Reftest(E, id);
    ptr_to_str->member2[0]->member1 = *SigVal;
}

Example* Reftest(Example* E, unsigned index)
{
    return E->member2[index];
}
```

#### Example output

```
ids (member1) pointed from the array inside ex1: 10 11 12 13 14 
member1 for ex1: 42
```

And you see that 42, the value of `test`, gets set in `ex1` using a few references